# How do I do a cross-DB MERGE INTO into an identical table while maintaining an identity key?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, merge

I have two tables on two different databases, DB1.Category and DB2.Category.

I need to merge all values so that DB1.Category and DB2.Category are identical, but I need to maintain the PK ID, CategoryID.

The CategoryID is an identity column with an increment and seed of 1 in DB1, but no identity in DB2.

Is there a way to sync all data in these tables from DB1 to DB2 while maintaining the PK?

This is what I have so far:

```
MERGE DB1.dbo.Category AS TARGET
USING DB2.dbo.Category AS SOURCE
ON (TARGET.MarketplaceName = SOURCE.MarketplaceName
    AND TARGET.MarketplaceCategoryCode = SOURCE.MarketplaceCategoryCode
    AND TARGET.MarketplaceCategoryName = SOURCE.MarketplaceCategoryName)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    INSERT(--*FIELDS*-
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused by your question.  The Title says "Identical table" but the body of your question you point out difference.  Can you provide the structure of the 2 tables?

Comment: This would be more appropriate as a comment :)

Comment: I agree but I cannot make comments as of yet except on my own post.